# Why my formula is repeating unique values

Tags: excel, formula

My data is in the Range A92:B100.

Col A has Date value & B has Quantity. Each month has 3 Dates, months are Jan, Feb & March.

I'm finding the Maximum value from each Month, and it should be 88, 324 & 254.

But the results are

```
88
88
325
325
254
254
```

The equation I've use is,

```
=IFERROR(IF(MONTH(A92) <>MONTH(A93), " ", MAX(MONTH($A$92:$A$100)=MONTH(A92),$B$92:$B$100)))," "))
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. Month(A92)<>Month(A93) will only occur on the last instance of the month. The first two instances will evaluate this as false and thus provide you with a value.

Change your formula to:

> IFERROR(IF(MONTH(A92) = MONTH(A93)," ",MAX(MONTH($A$92:$A$100)=MONTH(A92) ,$B$92:$B$100)))," "))

To only display the max value at the last instance of a month.

**EDIT** as OP added extra criteria to its question:

In col C add the unique values of the months.
In col D add the following function:

> =Max(Month($A$92:$A$100)=MONTH(C92),$B$92:$B$100)

Comment: I've tried in the way u have suggested, but it generates unique values along with blank cells in between the 3. 

I want 3 unique values in sequence like from A92:A94, 
88
325
354
Just chk.

Comment: Then you would have to add a helper column to display the unique months first.

Comment: ,, your second formula, 

=Max(Month($A$92:$A$100)=MONTH(C92),$B$92:$B$100), 
Will produce duplicate values not the unique. And as you have written in C92 put unique list of months, so could you suggest the formula? 

And my basic need is a single formula.

Comment: Just copy the row and click the remove duplicates button.

Comment: Now myself got the solution for both, so for the benefit of others I've decided to to post both the FORMULAS. 

1. To create unique list. 
2. Find Maximum of Unique values. 

IFERROR(INDEX($A$62:$A$74,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF ($E$61:E61,$A$62:$A$74),0,0),0))," ") 

NB: FORMULA cell is E62. 

=MAX(IF ($A$62:$A$74=$E62,$B$62:$B$74))

NB: FORMULA cell is F62. 

Both are an array formula. If any one feels both formula can be combined just using &" "& to, will produce Unique value along with Maximum in a cell. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS You better post it as an answer then. Makes it easier to read.

Comment: ,, unfortunately I can't do this, coz I don't have required credit points. You just edit it. 